# Posting a Guest Entry using AMP

Tags: plugin-guestentries

The question isn't that relevant to Craft's scope but it bounds to understand How entry from front end is processed... I think.

Thanks to P&T I'm learning on [GuestEntries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) plugin to send a POST request using [AMP-FORM](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form). A validation and sending is done via their JavaScript where XHR request is sent without a full load of the page. So AJAX request.
One of AMP's requirements were to set a `headers` for [CORS](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cors-requests.md) requests.

So I set the header in my .htaccess file like this:

```
Header set AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin "https://example.craft.dev"
```

With no `header` set I couldn't pass through validation.

After fulfilling AMP's requirements to submit a AMP-FORM I get this error:

```
POST https://example.craft.dev/someURI/send?__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.craft.dev 
400 (Bad Request)
```

This is my simple form I'm sending:

```
<form method="post" action-xhr="{{ craft.request.url }}" target="_top" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- {{ getCsrfInput() }} -->

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="guestEntries/saveEntry">
    <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="18">
    <input type="text" name="title">

    <input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

I had to comment `getCsrfInput()` because It was throwing me an error about some polifiling JSON or something.
I hope You folks can give me some pointers Whether Craft can handle it.

Comment: I've got 0 experience with AMP, but I'd guess you're getting the 400 bad request response because you've commented out the `getCsrfInput()`, which includes the CSRF token. I'd put that back in and troubleshoot the original error you received.

Comment: @Brad Bell I've commented out the `getCsrfInput()` because a token is created by their JavaScript. But thanks for joining in Brad. I'll try to troubleshoot it even with guys from AMP team.